# How to read environment variables inside docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to pass configuration parameters during runtime and feed it to the one of the configuration file inside the docker container.  How do i do it?

Here is what i am trying to do but the values are not being populated inside the configuration file.

```
docker run -d -e INPUT_PORT='5044' -e KAFKA_TOPIC='APP_LOG' -e KAFKA_HOST='169.20.240.199' -e KAFKA_PORT='32249' 9526492759f0
```

My configuration file inside the container (logstash.conf)

```
input {
  tcp {
 port => $INPUT_PORT
}
}
output {
kafka {
topic_id=>"$KAFKA_TOPIC"
bootstrap_servers=>"$KAFKA_HOST:$KAFKA_PORT"
codec => plain {
    format => "%{message}"
}
}
}
```

My Docker file:

```
FROM mamohr/centos-java

ENV LOGSTASH_VERSION 6.2.4

COPY logstash.conf /opt

RUN cd /opt && \
yum -y install vim && \
yum -y install wget && \
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/logstash/logstash-6.2.4.tar.gz && 
\
chmod +x logstash-6.2.4.tar.gz && \
tar -xvf logstash-6.2.4.tar.gz && \
mv logstash-6.2.4 logstash && \
mv logstash.conf /opt/logstash/bin
CMD ["/opt/logstash/bin/logstash", "-f", "/opt/logstash/bin/logstash.conf"]
```

Could someone advise please?

Comment: in a lot of case, running `docker exec my_container_name env` returns GNU/Linux environment variables !

Answer (score 1):

Docker sets environment variables in such a way that it is comparable to setting them using any other method.

Logstash does support reading environment variables in its config file, but it requires using the `${VAR}` syntax instead of `$VAR`.

You can see Docker setting an environment variable by doing tho following:

```
docker run --rm -it -e FOO=bar ubuntu bash
root@038e08de543d:/# env
HOSTNAME=038e08de543d
TERM=xterm
FOO=bar
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Note that there is a `FOO=bar` line showing that the FOO variable was indeed set by Docker.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html for full details on using an environment variable from a logstash.conf file.